# file uploads gets failed

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

when i try to upload an image,its not uploading at all and my code is here

```
public function image_upload($path)
{

    if($_FILES)
    {

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'.$path.'/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '5000';
        $config['max_width'] = '4000';
        $config['max_height'] = '6500';
        $config['file_name'] ='img';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if(! $this->upload->do_upload("file"))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message',$this->upload->display_errors());
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = './uploads/'.$path.'/'.$this->upload->file_name;
            $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
            $config['width'] = 200;
            $config['height'] = 150;
            $config['new_image'] = './uploads/'.$path.'/thumb/';
            $this->load->library('image_lib',$config);
            if(! $this->image_lib->resize())
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message',$this->image_lib->display_errors());
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return $this->upload->file_name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my view page is this

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/add_staff" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

           <tr>
              <td>Photo</td>
              <td><input type="file" id="file" name="file"></td>                                    
            </tr>  

           <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td> <input class="btn btn-primary save-btn" type="submit" value="Save" > </td>
            </tr>
   </form>
```

my cntroller looks like this

```
public function add_staff()
{
    $data['active_mn'] = 'add_staff';

    if($_POST)
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');                  
        if($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {
            if( ! $this->image_upload($path = 'staff') )
            {
                $photo = '';
            }
            else
            {
                $photo = $this->upload->file_name;
            }
            $data = array('photo'=>$photo);
            $status = $this->admin_model->db_insert($table='staff',$data);

            if($status)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Staff added Successfully');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Insertion failed');
            }

            redirect('admin/view_staff');               
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('admin/add_staff',$data);
}
```

i had gone through several ways but didn't got an solution for this.Will it be the system files problem?.

Comment: And where is the code you are using to get the file from `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];` ?  Which is the physical phile ( pun intended )

Comment: check the image size that you r trying to upload. in php default is 8M if you try to upload beyond this limit it wont upload. and if you want to increase upload limit change php.ini with new limits

Comment: no the image size that i used is less than 8M only

Comment: i didnt used any tmp_name

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to upload multiple images

```
if(isset($_GET['did']))
{
    $id = $_GET['did'];
    $part = "img/";
    $img = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbproduct_detail WHERE p_id = '$id'");
    while($r = mysql_fetch_object($img))
    {
        $old = $r->profile;
        unlink($part.$old);

    }
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbproduct_detail WHERE p_id = '$id'");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbproduct WHERE id = '$id'");
}


if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    $product_name = $_POST['product_name'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbproduct(product_name) VALUES('$product_name')");
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    if($id > 0)
    {
        foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $i => $tmp_name)
        {
            $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
            $filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
            $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
            $filetmp  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $store    = rand(0,13248575858).$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];


            if(move_uploaded_file($filetmp,"img/".$store))
            {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbproduct_detail(p_id,file_name,file_size,file_ext,profile) VALUES('$id','$filename','$filesize','$filetype','$store')");
            }

        }
   }


}?>
```

here is view part

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table class="table">
            <tr>                    
                <td>
                    <label>ProductName</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_name" class="form-control">
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Profile</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple class="form-control">                     
                    </div>
                </td> 

            </tr>



            <tr>                    
                <td>
                    <label>ProductName</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_name" class="form-control">
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Profile</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple class="form-control">                     
                    </div>
                </td> 

            </tr>
         <input type="submit" value="upload" class="btn btn-primary" name="upload">
    </table>
 </form>
```

Here is sql

```html
CREATE TABLE `tbproduct_detail` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 
 `p_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  `file_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 
 `file_size` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

  `file_ext` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 
 `profile` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

CREATE TABLE `tbproduct` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: i don't need to upload multiple images

Comment: u can try even 1 image,it doesn't problem :) @MOHAMMED